# Who is the artist for the Kitty and Peter pages?

Tags: marvel, x-men, all-new-x-men

*All-New X-Men* issue 25 has a ton of guest artists, each doing a page or two. In the issue, there's a two page story of Kitty and Piotr that's in an adorable art style. Since the pages don't have labels for who drew what, I have no idea who drew this.

Who drew the Kitty and Piotr pages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Comic Book Resources's review](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=user_review&id=7182) identifies it as Maris Wicks.

> and creators not normally associated with superheroes (Maris Wicks, Jason Shiga, Kent Williams).

and continues

> There are a few pages that work well when it comes to telling an actual story. The two-page past-and-future story of Kitty Pryde and Colossus, **courtesy Bendis and Wicks,** is hysterically funny. Bendis starts with highlighting the various obstacles in their path throughout the years, and then suddenly makes them more and more (deliberately) ridiculous without batting an eye.

On his tumblr, [Maris Wicks](http://mariswicks.tumblr.com/post/82301885040/i-had-the-pleasure-of-contributing-to-issue-25-of) confirms this.

> I had the pleasure of contributing to issue #25 of ALL-NEW X-MEN!  And I got to do a Kitty-Peter-themed 2 pages…SO. AWESOME.  This was so much fun to work on, and I’m beside some of my favorite people in comics.  A big thanks to Brian Michael Bendis and the folks at Marvel for letting me jump on this band wagon!